# LED light stopped on my eZ430-F2013 development tool

Tags: msp430

I am trying to make morse code on the eZ430-F2013. All of the sudden my LED stopped blinking. I pulled USB out after running sample LED blinking code. Now it doesn't blink when I plug it in. Does it mean it broke? how do I reset it?

Comment: Re-flash the board and hold reset button while you plug it in.

Comment: Why do you tag this as `c` and `assembly` - I don't see any code here nor any question related to code.

Comment: its an "usb" drive. I dont see any reset button on it??

Comment: Your description is unclear. Did you ever program it with your own code, or with sample code from TI; or were you just using the already-programmed sample code it shipped with?